# Copy traces in a loop OBSPY

Tags: python, loops, copy, obspy

I have several traces which I imported from a folder, and I need to copy them for further processing. I was trying to copy them into a loop with the original procedure for copying one trace

```
for i in range(550):
    tr[i] = st[i].copy()
```

but it complains that `tr` is not defined. How can I define `tr` then? I tried the standard procedure, but not working!

Comment: What is the "standard procedure"? What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```
for tr in st:
   tr_copy = tr.copy()
```